# Python exeception handler not working as expected

Tags: python, function, try-except

I‘m writing an interactive calculator with dozens of my own functions. Some functions have string arguments, and some have number arguments.

For the string case, if I enter a string, by accident, without quotes I’d like the script to print out my own error message saying, “argument must be a quoted string” and then continue.

Here’s the shape of the kind of functions I'm writing

```
def sample_function(x):
        try:
              if type(x) is str:
                   # do some calculation
                   print(x)
              else:
                   pass
        except NameError:
                   print(“ argument must be a quoted string”)
```

As long as I enter sample_function('a') everything is fine, but if I enter samole_function(a),
instead of printing my message and continuing, the script terminates with the system error message

```
    NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

There must be a way to get the exection handler to do what I want.

Comment: That's because the NameError is raised before you even call the function, so you never even reach the try-except block.

Comment: Typically, you aren't supposed to *catch* a `NameError`; you are supposed to fix the code that generates it.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because `a` is not defined. Shocking, I know.

You're referencing an object named `a`, but you haven't created it. It's the same thing as trying to print a variable that doesn't exist.

```
>>> print(mystring)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mystring' is not defined
```

This works, though.

```
>>> mystring="Hello world!"
>>> print(mystring)
Hello world!
```

See?

```
def sample_function(x):
    # Lose the try/except here
    if type(x) is str:
        # do some calculation
        print(x)
    else:
        print("That wasn't a string!")

                         
# This doesn't work
try:
    sample_function(a)
except NameError:
    print("That didn't work")

# This works
a = "a string"
sample_function(a)

# And this works too
a = 123
sample_function(a)

# Output:
#   That didn't work
#   a string
#   That wasn't a string!
```